# Regex used within python giving unknown results

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using `regular expression` to find phone numbers from two different sites. when I tried with below pattern to scrape the two phone numbers locally then it works flawlessly. However, when i try the same in the websites, It no longer works. It only fetches two unidentified numbers `1999` and `8211`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import requests, re

links=[
    'http://www.latamcham.org/contact-us/',
    'http://www.cityscape.com.sg/?page_id=37'
    ]

def FetchPhone(site):
    res = requests.get(site).text
    phone = re.findall(r"\+?[\d]+\s?[\d]+\s?[\d]+",res)[0]  #I'm not sure if it is an ideal pattern. Works locally though
    print(phone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for link in links:
        FetchPhone(link)
```

The output I wish to have:

```
+65 6881 9083
+65 93895060
```

This is what I meant by locally:

```
import re

phonelist = "+65 6881 9083,+65 93895060"

phone = [item for item in re.findall(r"\+?[\d]+\s?[\d]+\s?[\d]+",phonelist)]
print(phone)  #it can print them
```

Post script: the phone numbers are not generated dynamically. When I print text then I can see the `numbers` in the console.

Comment: What do you mean by scraping them locally? Have you tried printing `res` and seeing if it contains the phone numbers?

Comment: Try `r"\+?\d{1,3}\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}"`

Comment: I tried with your suggested expression @Wiktor Stribiżew and got this `3333333333,14465014376`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case below regex should return required output

```
r"\+\d{2}\s\d{4}\s?\d{4}"
```

Note that it can be applied to mentioned schemas:

- +65 6881 9083
- +65 93895060

and might not work in other cases

Comment: Thanks for the solution sir. I know it won't work in other cases. However, I intended to see how regex can be applied in parsing phone numbers from the web.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `\d+\s?\d+` which will match `9 9`, `99` and `1999` because the `+` quantifier allows the first `\d+` to grab as many digits as it can while leaving at least one digit to the others. One solution is to state a specific number of repetitions you want (like in Andersson's answer).

I suggest you try regex101.com, it will highlight to help you visualize what the regex is matching and capturing. There you can paste an example of the text you want to search and tweak your regex.